# Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to add multiple video_id(videolinks) simultaneously wtih same title and category here is my form code please do some help

```
class AddVideoViaLinkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=True,min_length=1,max_length=200)
    video_id = forms.CharField(required=True,min_length=1,max_length=20)
    category = forms.CharField(required=True,min_length=1,max_length=20)
    description = forms.CharField(required=True,min_length=1,max_length=20)

    def clean_title(self):
      title = self.cleaned_data.get('title')
        if title.strip()=='':
          raise  forms.ValidationError('Enter a Valid Title')
        else:
            return title    
    def clean_description(self):
        description = self.cleaned_data.get('description')
        if description.strip()=='':
          raise  forms.ValidationError('Enter a Valid Description')
        else:
            return description    

class Meta:
    model = Videos
        fields = ('title','video_id','category','description')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Meta should belong to AddVideoViaLinkForm. In this class you can add save function which will do this for you:

```
def save(self):
    ids = self.cleaned_data['video_id'].split(",")# it depends what is your id separator
    title = self.cleaned_data['title']
    for id in ids:
        Videos.objects.create(video_id=id, title=title, ...)
```